# Sharing elevation layer to ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-enterprise, web-scene

I have a problem sharing a ground layer to ArcGIS Enterprise as elevation layer. My data is a raster from a database and I try to share it using "share as web layer". but the option is disabled. I don't know why this happen but if I try to share it as a 2D layer which become an image layer in enterprise, it can be done. Anybody have the same problem with this?

[image: Arcpro]

Comment: Have you read the [Help file](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/publish-elevation-layers.htm)?

Comment: Yes i did, but i dont want to publish it as a Hosted Layer. The data already registered in database.